# Get state and make dispatch from middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In my React application i'm using Long-polling API. In order to automatically send requests on every response i use middleware. But before sending new request, i have to save received data in store. More than that, i want to dispatch another action inside my middleware. So my structure looks like this:

InitLongPoll() -> SendRequest(data) -> ReceiveResponse(data)* -> SendRequest(data)

'*' is my middleware. From there i'm saving data to the store using `store.dispatch(responseData)` and sending new request using `store.dispatch(sendRequest(authData))`.

Is it okay to receive that authData using `store.getState().authReducer`? As far as i know, my middleware should be a pure function and shouldn't depend on external data (store). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it okay to receive that authData using
>   store.getState().authReducer? As far as i know, my middleware should
>   be a pure function and shouldn't depend on external data (store).

Yes it is. Middleware is the way to introduce side effects into the redux loop, and it can't be a pure function. Your own middleware has a side effect - polling the server.

A redux middleware is the anti-thesis of a pure function, which is defined as:

> 1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any
>      hidden information or state that may change while program execution
>      proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it
>      depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output
>      to I/O devices (usually—see below).

You can also see in the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js) source code, that it uses `getState`:

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}
```